# Australia ETA subclass 601 and 600

Tags: visas, australia, multiple-entry, eta, application-status

I registered through the Australian ETA apication subclass 601. I paid AUD 20. Then I could not access the link given. I accidentally created my immigration account on the Australian home affairs portal. I submitted all documents under subclass 600, paid another AUD 190. Is there a problem now? Since I applied twice (600 and 601).

Comment: I have so many questions. What is your nationality? Was your 601 ETA application successful?  Have you received your 600 visitor visa yet?

Comment: I am Malaysian. My ETA 601 was submitted but yet to attach supporting documents at form 1554. Then I accidentally submitted another visitor subclass 600 application. Both had not granted yet. Should I withdraw either  one and request for refund?

Comment: ETA grants are usually more or less instant.  Do you have previous immigration history to Australia, or answer "yes" to any of the questions about criminal records etc?